# Rails - Nested fields with cocoon not displaying errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I'm using cocoon gem for nested fields, and I have a nested attribute like this (slim code):

```
      = f.simple_fields_for :cliente_cnpjs do |cnpj|
        = render 'cliente_cnpj_fields', f: cnpj
      .links
        = link_to_add_association "<i class='fa fa-plus-circle'> </i> Adicionar CNPJ".html_safe, f, :cliente_cnpjs
```

And I have a validation on my model for minimum length:

```
  validates :cliente_cnpjs, :length => { :minimum => 1 }
```

So, if I try save without adding any of that attribute, it doesn't save, but also doesn't display the error on the field. I debugged on my create/update actions and the error is on the object, as it supposed to be... (as follows):

```
errors ["Cliente cnpjs is too short (minimum: 1 chars)"]
```

It returns to the form displaying there's a validation errors, but shows nothing in the field! Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Hi Ronan, I currently have a similar problem, how were you able to resolve the problem?